# Chartist JS, line graph going under X axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, chartist.js

Currently I'm using the Chartist JS jQuery plugin and I'm having this issue where one of the function is going below x axis even though it doesn't have any negative points.

Is there anyway to avoid this issue, please check the image to further understanding.

[image]

The code

```
var options = {
    low: 0,
    fullWidth: true,
    height: '225px',
    chartPadding: {
        left: 0,
        right: 40,
    },
    showArea: true,
    onlyInteger:true,
    bezierCurve:false
};

$.ajax({
    url: $('.ct-log-lead').data('url'),
    method: 'GET',
    data: {customerId:$('.ct-log-lead').data('id'),phoneNumber: $('.ct-log-lead').data('phone')},
    success: function (d) {

        data = {
            labels: d[0],
            datasets: d[1]
        };                     

//        var leadsLastSevenDays = 0;
//        data.datasets[0].forEach(function (value) {
//            leadsLastSevenDays += value;
//        })        
//         $('.call-seven').html(d[2]);         

        var a = new Chartist.Line('.ct-log-lead', {
            labels: data.labels,
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Form Leads',
                    data: data.datasets[0]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Call Logs',
                    data: data.datasets[1]
                }
            ],

        }, options);
    }
});
```

THanks

Comment: your code if you may?

Comment: please check, I added the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem just add this in  your options variable and for more information By default Chartist uses a cardinal spline algorithm to smooth the lines.You can customize it eaisly.

```
 lineSmooth: Chartist.Interpolation.simple({
    divisor: 2
  }),
```

see the both of fiddles 
http://jsfiddle.net/Van_Jarvis/3uL7zu4o/113/

http://jsfiddle.net/3uL7zu4o/114/

Answer (score 0):

In options you can pass **bezierCurve** so that you will not get smooth curves,

```
var options = {
     bezierCurve:false
  }
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

Comment: @JGEstevez, please go through this [discussion](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/424), which version of chart.js are you using? If it's an older version I recommend using [this](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js) one. I hope this latest version solves your issue.

Comment: This is for Chart.js not Chartist.js ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The standard line interpolation / smoothing can cause unwanted artifacts. Use the simple interpolation as an alternative:

http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#example-line-simple-smoothing